# Is it safe to use '*' as the origin of a message from inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain

The problem was, that I had an `<iframe>` with dynamically changing content. I couldn't find any other way to dynamically change the height of the `<iframe>` element than sending new height each time when it changes to the bloggers website by `parent.postMessage`. The solution works (maybe it can help others, but the thing is that I'm not sure if I have done it in a safe way.

I just want to ask if it's safe to use `window.parent.postMessage('Some message', '*')` in that way?

Embeded site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var framesHeight = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        var newFramesHeight = window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetHeight;
        if (newFramesHeight !== framesHeight) {
            window.parent.postMessage(newFramesHeight, '*');
            framesHeight = newFramesHeight;
        }
    }, 500);
</script>
```

As you can see, each time when the hight changes I send a new message.

On the bloggers website I want to embed this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('message', function (evt) {
        if (evt.origin === 'http://mypage.com' && !isNaN(evt.data)) {
            document.getElementById('embedID').style.height = evt.data+'px';
        } 
   }, false);
</script>
<iframe id="embedID" src="http://mypage.com/embed/11" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```